# Capacitor Camera plugin error - Object: {"message":"Unable to create photo on disk"}

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I install latest ionic + capacitor

I follow the tutorial from official capacitor website (https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/guides/ionic-framework-app)

When I build my project and run it on Android I get and error:

"Camera plugin error - Object: {"message":"Unable to create photo on disk"}"

```
const image = await Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
  quality: 100,
  allowEditing: false,
  resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl,
  source: CameraSource.Camera
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue happens only when saveToGallery is set to true.

This works:

```
const image = await Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
  quality: 100,
  allowEditing: false,
  resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl,
  source: CameraSource.Camera,
  saveToGallery: false
});
```

Comment: Tried it, no luck. @capacitor/camera 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the same issue with `source: CameraSource.Photos`, than check https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/2060

As for me, `correctOrientation: false` helped

Comment: Tried it, no luck. @capacitor/camera 1.3.0

Comment: IDK, try this config:
"@capacitor/camera": "^1.0.5"
const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
 allowEditing: false,
 resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl,
 saveToGallery: false,
 correctOrientation: true
});